# "a friend of mine" / "the wife of Mr Black"

Tags: possessive-pronouns

Why **"a friend of mine"** is correct, but "the wife of Mr Black" isn't correct (only Mr Black's wife)? What is the difference in terms of grammar?

If there are some other examples in that rule, it would be nice to have a look at them.

[image: The picture from the book]

Comment: "the wife of Mr Black"  is correct grammar.  It is rarer than the form with 's  but both mean the same.  Can you give an example of why you think it isn't correct.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on an incorrect assumption.

Comment: @James K, My grammar book says that: "Have you met Mr Black’s wife? (not the wife of Mr Black)" - Murphy - Essential grammar in use. Unit 64.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, It's not my assumption. It's from English grammar book.

Comment: Your book is clearly wrong.

Comment: "The wife of Mr Black" is less common but not a grammar mistake.  However, when talking about relationships "Mr Black's wife" is better English.  Your book may be unclear on which aspects are grammar rules and which aspects are tendencies and trends.

Comment: "Jane Black is the wife of John Black, the principal of the college" is fine, but it would sound rather stiff and formal to say "Have you met the wife of John Black?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is whether we are talking about the only one of a category or if there are multiple. With singular (Mr. Black here has only one wife), the shorter form is preferable and the longer with "of" is discouraged (not wrong - also your book doesn't say so). If Mr. Black had multiple wives, it could only be "a wife of Mr. Black". This is also the case in your example with "a friend of mine".

Short form: **a X of Y** - OK. **the X of Y** - discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in grammar is that with personal pronouns we use the independent possessive form after possessive *of*: "of mine", "of yours", "of his", "or hers", "of ours", "of theirs".

There is no reason for this (there might be a historical one, but even if there is, it's irrelevant): it just happens to be the way modern English is.

This only applies to possessive *of*: we say "suspicious of him/them/you/me".

Comment: It would be simplier to understand your text with some examples.

Comment: We also use it with names. **A friend of Fred's.** For some reason the dictionaries like to use "friend" in their examples.